# add button to order view after tracking number is added to order

Tags: event-observer, sales-order

is it possible to add custom button to order view when tracking number is added?

i have event observer(`<sales_order_shipment_save_before>`) that adds tracking number to order when button submit shipment has been pressed by admin
like this: observer.php:

```
public function salesOrderShipmentSaveBefore($observer)

        {
    $trackNumber='111111111';
                        $track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')
                                    ->setNumber($trackNumber) 
                                    ->setCarrierCode('mycompany_mycarrier')
                                    ->setTitle('My Carrier'); 
                        $shipment->addTrack($track);
```

but how can i add custom button to order view after tracking number is added?
i know that if use this event `<core_block_abstract_to_html_before>`
and this function in observer.php file:

```
public function labelButton($observer)
    {
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getData( 'block' );

                if(get_class($block) =='Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View'
                    && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales_order')
                {
                    $block->addButton('label', array(
                        'label'     => 'Label',
                        'class'     => 'go'
                    ));
                }
```

button is added excatly where i need, but i need this button to be visible only if the tracking number is added to order, is it doable? any help would be good.
or is there some way that i could make `<core_block_abstract_to_html_before>` event to happen only if `<sales_order_shipment_save_before>` event has already happened?

**EDIT**

ok finally now i am moveing somwhere!

with your suggestion `smiggle` i edit my code like this:

```
public function labelButton($observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getData( 'block' );

    if(get_class($block) =='Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View'
        && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales_order')
    {
        $carrier = $block->getOrder()->getShippingCarrier();
        $order = $block->getOrder();
        $orderIncrementId=$order->getIncrementId();
        $oOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
        $storeID = $oOrder->getData('store_id');
        $shipping = $oOrder->getShippingDescription();

//var_dump($shipping); die();

        if ($carrier instanceof Mage_Shippping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
            && $carrier->isTrackingAvailable()) {
                $block->addButton('label', array(
                   'label'     => 'Label',
                   'class'     => 'go'
                ));
        }
}
```

with var_dump function i am getting the right shiping description from "Shipping & Handling Information" field in order view, but still how can i get if there is tracking number set in that field? i did not used isTrackingAvailable function in my carrier which i made my self but my carrier extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract and also my carrier creates tracking numbers automatically like i mentioned before with `<sales_order_shipment_save_before>` event, so the problem is, if in that current order customer has chosed my cretaed carrier then isTrackingAvailable function returns false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are in the best place for do doing this, but a solution might be:

```
public function labelButton($observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getData( 'block' );

    if(get_class($block) =='Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View'
        && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales_order')
    {
        $carrier = $block->getOrder()->getShippingCarrier();

        if ($carrier instanceof Mage_Shippping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
            && $carrier->isTrackingAvailable()) {
                $block->addButton('label', array(
                   'label'     => 'Label',
                   'class'     => 'go'
                ));
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

You can try to get the track information with `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::getTracksCollection()`.

Comment: tried your version, but error apears and says:  Call to a member function getShippingCarrier() on a non-object in Observer.php file. From this i conclude that i can not get order details from <core_block_abstract_to_html_before> event

Comment: i wonder maybe there is way that i could add button right after i add tracking number. inside this function: salesOrderShipmentSaveBefore(); but then there is question will button be visible in other order views where tracking number has not been added to specific order yet

Comment: edited my question

Comment: found solution! see answear bellow. thank you smiggle.

Answer (score 0):

solution for this was:

```
public function labelButton($observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getData( 'block' );

    if(get_class($block) =='Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View'
        && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales_order')
    {
        $carrier = $block->getOrder()->getShippingCarrier();
        $order = $block->getOrder();
        $orderIncrementId=$order->getIncrementId();
        $oOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);

        $shipment_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_shipment_collection')
            ->setOrderFilter($oOrder)
            ->load();
        foreach($shipment_collection as $shipment){
            foreach($shipment->getAllTracks() as $tracking_number){
            $trackNumber = $tracking_number->getNumber();
        }
        if(isset($trackNumber)){
            //var_dump($trackNumber);
            //die();
             $block->addButton('label', array(
                   'label'     => 'Label',
                   'class'     => 'go'
                ));
    }
}       

    }

}
```